# How to insert a checkmark symbol into state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

Am trying to use state to change the symbols on a button based on whether the button has been clicked or not but the state doesn't seem to accept the values unless they are strings

[Code in Vs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xq1X.png)

```js
// this piece of state right here returns an error
const [tick, setTick] = useState($#x2713);

// the state only allows premitive values, so it'll only work if it's a string
const [tick, setTick] = useStata("$#2713");
```

What's another solution to get to this outcome right here using state....
[Code in Vs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krBGr.png)

Comment: You should do this in your jsx. `ticked` should be a boolean, and your jsx should be like `ticked ? 'check' : 'not-check'`

Comment: FYI, the hex notation of a check mark in JS context is represented as text and so belongs between quotes. From JS perspective it is a string of multiple characters with no special meaning whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use React to write an HTML entity. To do so would require [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#dangerously-setting-the-inner-html) and as the name implies, it's not encouraged.

Instead, store the *state* of the button and use that state to render values

```jsx
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

return (
  <button onClick={() => setClicked(true)}>
    {clicked ? <>&#x2713;</> : <>&times;</>}
  </button>
);
```

[image: Edit flamboyant-rain-lfg39p]

Comment: Your approach is very appropriate, thanks for the assistance.